# Error -> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I created this Multiple Choice program and everything is fine and the right answer is printing out but I keep getting:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 at MultipleChoices.main(MultipleChoices.java:21)**

Can somebody tell me what I need to do to fix this error?

```
        for(int i = 0; i < student[i].length; i++){
            int rightAns = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < student[i].length; j++){
                if(student[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(key[j])){
                    rightAns++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: the problem is you are trying to get the 9th element of an array containing only 8 elements.

Comment: @Stultuske so how do i fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first for loop uses the wrong value. You should use student.length instead of student[i].

```
for(int i = 0; i < student.length; i++){
        int rightAns = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < student[i].length; j++){
            if(student[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(key[j])){
                rightAns++;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Student's " + i + "#correct answer: " + rightAns + "\n");
    }

}
```